# Why is a parameter with type "any" required

Tags: typescript, optional-parameters

I have a function with a single parameter of type `any`:

```
function doSomething(param: any) {
    // Do something with param
}
```

If I try and call this function with:

```
doSomething();
```

I get the error: "Expected 1 arguments, but got 0." I'm able to remove the error by passing `undefined` as the parameter:

```
doSomething(undefined);
```

Parameters which aren't passed default to `undefined`, so I'm not sure why explicitly passing `undefined` is required? Unfortunately the function is in a library so I am not able to mark the parameter as optional.

Answer (score 4):

Because your function signature tells there's a one parameter with type `any`. So you have to pass something when calling it. Note that `any` is also a type just like `string`, `number` etc.

And Typescript is a compile time program not a runtime program. So if you don't pass the argument when you using the function typescript is going to complain about it.

If that parameter is not required, you can make it optional with `?` mark.

```
function doSomething(param?: any) {
    // Do something with param
}
```

> The `any` type is useful when you don’t want to write out a long type just to convince TypeScript that a particular line of code is okay.

Comment: Is there any way of marking a parameter as optional without editing the declaration? Unfortunately the library I'm using doesn't mark optional parameters as optional.

Comment: In that case you can do something like `(doSomething as any)()` or replace the `any` with a proper type declaration. For example `(doSomething as () => void)()`

Comment: You can create wrapper function on top of it or you can change the typescript types but this maybe broke the library.